# How can i automatically move files based on their name?

Tags: windows

I have 13 folders containing scanned photographs. Some photographs have been renamed to the date on which they were taken, resulting in `YYYY.MM.DD.tif` name. It could potentially be `YYYY.MM.DD (###).tif` where ### is just a number. Others are just named `IMG_###.tif`

I would like to move the files with the `YYYY.MM.DD` name to a `YYYY\MM\DD` folder structure.

While the files are being moved, I would also like to append the original folder name to the end of the file name.

So, a file `01\2012.06.26 (1).tif` should end up `2012\06\26\2012.06.26 (1) - 01.tif`

Is there a Windows tool that can help me with this? Or do I need to resort to writing a custom app?

Comment: it would be helpful to indicate your OS. based on that there are different possibilities...

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post to specify that I am on Windows.

Comment: Which version of Windows( 7, vista, XP)?

Comment: I am Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [MoveOut](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/12/move-files-automatically/) (along with some scheduled tasks) to do this on Windows. That Ghacks article discusses MoveOut, and there seem to be some alternatives to it hyperlinked at the end. [QuickMove](http://www.ghacks.net/2012/06/21/quickmove-lets-you-move-files-automatically-in-windows/) also looks promising, though you might have to schedule it. I'd suggest [writing a regex](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/regex.html) to match the names of the files you'd like to move.

Comment: Looks promising, I will try it tonight.